# How to handle .owl file with sparql queries using java?

Tags: sparql, jena, owl, ontology, owl-api

I want to develop java application that displays knowledge or information inferred from cottonCrop ontology (.owl file)  (in form of GUI i.e table or tree - human understandable ) using sparql queries.

I want to make application similar to below reference link.
[ Reference link: http://agridaksh.iasri.res.in/Project/language.jsp ]

I have done comprehensive reading for Apache Jena / OWL API / Protege API.

Still I'm confused which framework I should use and how I built the application ?

Please share your views on this. I'm expecting detailed responses.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is the wrong platform for "expecting detailed tool details", see the guidelines. By the way, Protege is based on OWL API and Apache Jena is primarily designed for RDF and not OWL (especially not OWL 2). On the other hand, OWL API has no built-in SPARQL support. Apache Jena and RDF4J have this. Anyway, this question should be closed.

Comment: files *.owl could be either OWL/XML or RDF/XML. The first is [OWL-API](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi) format and it is only for OWL2 ontologies, the second is a w3c standard and it is for any rdf-graph. If you want OWL2+sparql you can take a look at [ONT-API](https://github.com/avicomp/ont-api) which is based on Jena, but implements OWL-API interfaces, otherwise pure Jena is more suitable for your purposes

Comment: @Sigrem Thank you for your guidance. Now file is of type owl/xml.  Which will suffice my requirements Apache Jena + sparql OR OWL-API + sparql?? I want to make application similar to below reference link. [ Reference link: http://agridaksh.iasri.res.in/Project/language.jsp ]. Can you please tell me how should I begin ?

Comment: The question is, what kind of queries do you need for your application. Remember, SPARQL is the RDF query language, thus, it doesn't have any convenience functionality to handle complex OWL structures. But as I said, If you only need simple queries, save your ontology as RDF/XML and use plain Apache Jena.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable suggestions.